# Change the image of a specific button pressed in a UITableview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a dynamic tableview which has a prototype cell with a button that, when pressed, plays a song.

I'd like for the background image on the button to change to a "stop" icon when the user presses the button to play the song, and for it to change to a "play" icon when the user presses it once again to stop the song.

To accomplish this I've been trying to use: 
`[self.beatPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImageimageNamed:@"play.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

My issue is that I haven't figured out how to change only the button in the row that is being pressed since I'm using prototype cells. I've been hoping to find a method like `didSelectObjectAtRow:atIndexPath:` because `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will fire when the row is pressed, but not a button on it (unless I'm mistaken). Maybe I should be using a tag? I'm not sure. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
My code is outside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Here is sample code -

```
- (IBAction)playStopBeat:(UIButton*)sender event:(id)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if([self.audioPlayer isPlaying])
    {
        [self.beatPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
        self.isPlaying = NO;
        self.audioPlayer = nil;
    }
    else {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self.beatPlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1){
            [self.beatPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2){
...
//code to play song
```

Comment: is the action happening in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or in some action sent by the button?

Comment: can you provide some code? what action is associated to the button?

Comment: i've updated my question to provide more context. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tags, like you suggested. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method give each cell a tag:

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
```

also set each target on the cells:

```
[cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(play:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in your play method, use your tag for your array or w/e:

```
- (IBAction)play:sender
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
     NSLog(@"tag = %d", cell.tag);

     if(tag == 0)
     {
          //you could also use a switch statement 
     } else if(tag == 1) {

     }
}
```

::EDIT:: (answer to comment)

To disable the other buttons, in your play method:

```
- (IBAction)play:sender
{
     .........
     ....other code....

     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;

     for(int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++)
     {
        UITableViewCell *tempCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

        if(tempCell.tag != cell.tag)
        {

            [cell.playButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
     }
}
```

In doing this though, after the song is done playing you must set them all back to enabled. This would be done in the MediaPlayers delegate method: didFinishPlaying.

Comment: thanks my friend. i was able to get this to work with your help.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to disable interaction with buttons at other tag indices? For example if I have 5 rows and I've pushed the button at tag #2, then buttons at tags 0-1 and 3-5 would be disabled. If you do know then I can pose another question and place a link to it so that you can answer it.

Comment: @OrpheusMercury I just added some code to my original answer, let me know if that helps. I believe it should be valid, I did not test in xcode though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I see where your head is at with this but i actually can't get [cell.playButton setEnabled:NO] to work outside of cellforrowatindexpath because cell doesn't recognize playButton. I'm trying to figure out alternative code. any thoughts?

Comment: @OrpheusMercury you should get access to each cell to set the play button enabled in that loop by using the cellForRowAtIndexPath method; that is not working for you?

Comment: I wasn't able to access each cell through that method but through modifying your answer i was able to figure this out. thanks vey much!

Comment: @OrpheusMercury Hi, I am having a very similar problem with being able to access the cell. Could you explain how you modified the answer? Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using target/action, the sender argument will contain the button that was tapped. Instead of referring to the button as self.beatPlayButton, just use sender, so `[sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`